# Salesforce: Apex trigger to check whether email domain exists

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I want to find out whether the email domain exist in the database. Eg: If xxx@abc.com is going to be inserted, I want to check email with the same domain(abc.com) already exist or not. Following is the code to check the whole email exist.

```
trigger trig_Contact_webToContact on Contact (before insert) 
{
  final String errMsg = 'The email already exists on another Contact: ';
  Set< String > emailSet = new Set< String >();
  for( Contact c : Trigger.new ) emailSet.add( c.Email );

  Map< String, Id > duplicateContactMap = new Map< String, Id >();

  for( Contact c : [select Id, Email from Contact where Email = :emailSet] )
    duplicateContactMap.put( c.Email, c.Id );

  for( Contact c : Trigger.new ){
    Id duplicateContactId = duplicateContactMap.get( c.Email );
    if( duplicateContactId != null )
      c.addError( errMsg + duplicateContactId );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to find out, whether an email with same domain exist in the salesforce or not. If so error msg need to be popped up, like "An email with same domain already exists"

Comment: I understand that. What is your question? Is your question "does my code do what I want"? If you have a problem with your code, like, it doesn't do what you want, state that. Is smth wrong with your code? What is your problem?

Comment: My code doesn't look only for domain, but for the whole email address. I need to modify it for, look only for the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get only domain from email, but not the whole email:

```
Set< String > emailDomainSet = new Set< String >();
for( Contact c : Trigger.new ) {
  if (String.isBlank(c.Email)) continue;
  int indexOfAt = c.Email.indexOf('@');
  if (indexOfAt > 0) emailDomainSet.add( c.Email.substring(indexOfAt) );
}
```

then, in your case, you need to use [query(queryString)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_query) method. Compose a SOQL string first

```
string queryString = 'select name from Contact where  ';
string whereClause = ' ';
for (string domainItem : emailDomainSet) {
  whereClause += ' or Email like \'%'+domainItem + '\' ';
}    
whereClause = whereClause.substring(4);//remove first or in where clause
queryString += whereClause;
```

then, run it.
Instead of

```
for( Contact c : [select Id, Email from Contact where Email = :emailSet] )
```

you should put

```
for( Contact c : (List<Contact>)Database.query(queryString) )
```